# MVC Datatype Currency trigger numeric keypad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

My Model has a Dataype(Datatype.Currency) whic is a decimal object.

I am trying to force the view to trigger a Numeric keypad on ipad/iphone when the user clicks into it.  It works when the object is an INT but will not work for Decimal.

Heres a snippet of the model (I've tried using regular expressions to no avail):

```
 [Display(Name = "Bid Price")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)")]
        public decimal BidPrice { get; set; }
```

Here is a snippet of the view.  IS there a way to use the new { @inputtype = "number"} somehow?

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BidPrice, new { @type= "number" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BidPrice)
            </div>
```

Please help if you have ever got this to work.

Comment: Yes that worked!  I dont know how many sites i looked at to try and find an answer to this.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EditorFor()` method does not support adding `htmlAttributes` unless your using MVC-5.1 or higher. If you are the the syntax is

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BidPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type= "number" } })
```

If your not, then you will need to use the `TextBoxFor()` method to add the attribute

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BidPrice, new { @type= "number" })
```