# How to add css in a htmlhelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In the asp.net mvc 4 developing,I write following code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.CreateTime,new {@class="form-control"}).   

@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.CreateTime,null,new {@class="form-control"})
```

These two ways didn't work! When I check the html code generated the class element didn't appear.

But when I write these codes,it is fine:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.CreateTime,new {@class="form-control"})
```

So tell me how to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Datatype Currency trigger numeric keypad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736531/mvc-datatype-currency-trigger-numeric-keypad)

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.EditorFor()` does not support HTML Attributes. Instead use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.CreateTime,new {@class="form-control"})
```

OR In case if you want to use @Html.EditorFor() then

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.CreateTime,"formcontrol",null)
```

CSS-

```
<style>
.formcontrol{
// your Code
}
</style>
```

Not tested but something to get started.

**EDITED**

Or use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#CreateTime').addClass('form-control');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `@EditorFor` simply generates the text box with a class=single-line. 
Try to use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead.