# required attribute not generating in mvc partial razor view (using Edmx Models)

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@model eDurar.Models.BuyOnlineAddress

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>BuyOnlineAddress</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Address Details
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details, new {@required="required" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

This is partial view, in the html generated, there is no required attribute

When I manually insert it in the html editor, works fine, but this method usually works for normal views

I haven't loaded any scripts this time

Comment: You can add html attributes using `EditorFor()` in MVC-5 (you need at least `MVC-5.1). Your `TextBoxFor()`. And do not use HTML-5 validation. Add a `[Required]` attribute to your model property so you get both clienst side and server side validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Datatype Currency trigger numeric keypad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736531/mvc-datatype-currency-trigger-numeric-keypad)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I use edmx models, can,t do annotations , usually this method works,

Comment: This is auto-generated code by MVC3 scafolder

Comment: It has never worked worked and never will. You adding `new {@required="required" }` as `additionalViewData`, not html attributes (your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Object%29). And do not use data models in a view when editing. Use view models.

Comment: @StephenMuecke tight schedule, cant don't that right now, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117593/discussion-between-arun-prasad-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got it now, I changed

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details, new {@required="required" })
```

to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Details, new {@required="required" })
```