# @Html.EditorFor required = "required" not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to validate @Html.EditorFor that it is required to input, but not working in asp.net mvc

```
<div class="form-group"> <label>First Name editor*</label>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Requester.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Requester.FirstName)
                                </div>
```

sorry for my simple question because it is really frustating try to fix this issue

my controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel.Ticket m)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DatabaseManager ctx = new DatabaseManager(true))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.TicketNo))
                {
                    m.TicketNo = TicketNo.Create(User.Identity.Name, "TICKET");
                }

                Ticket obj = ViewModel.Ticket.ConvertToTicketBusiness(m);
                obj.Requester = m.Requester.Email;
                obj.TicketStatus = TicketStatus.Open.ToString();
                obj.Escalation = User.Identity.Name;
                obj.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                obj.UpdatedBy = obj.CreatedBy;
                obj.UpdatedDate = obj.CreatedDate;
                if (obj.IsValid)
                {
                    obj = obj.Save();
                }

                Customer cust = ViewModel.Ticket.ConvertToCustomerBusiness(m.Requester);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cust.CreatedBy))
                {
                    cust.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    cust.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }

                cust.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                cust.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

                if (cust.IsValid)
                {
                    cust = cust.Save();
                }
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            ViewBag.SuccessMsg = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
            return View(m);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Inbox");
    }
```

thank you

Comment: Have you set it as required on the Model itself? If so, are you checking the ModelState on the controller?

Comment: yes already set the view model like this  `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Input is required.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } ` but about the ModelState, not yet but already checking my object isValid or not

Comment: Can I see the controller code?

Comment: yes sure, already update my question with my controller code, please check

Comment: At no point on the controller are you validating the data coming in? Try putting an if statement at the top of the controller which returns the view if the modelstate is invalid.

if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(m)
}

Comment: I just want to validating in client-side, already using required attribute with `@Html.TextAreaFor` it is working, but `@Html.EditorFor required = “required”` not working as expected

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a required attribute of it's correctly added to the model. Have you included Unobtrusive Ajax?

Comment: You using the wrong syntax for `EditorFor()` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736531/mvc-datatype-currency-trigger-numeric-keypad/35737082#35737082). And adding `required = "required"` is pointless anyway - that is HTML5 validation and will be ignored if you have included the necessary scripts for client side validation - `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` which use the validation attributes applied to your model properties

Comment: @scottdavidwalker yeah already add Unobtrusive Ajax, I remove the attribute but still same result

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh i see, but do you have any example to achive Html.EditorFor validation required, because I need to use that

Comment: Are you using MVC-5.1 or higher? Otherwise just use `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: oke, so my solution is using `TextBoxFor()` , thank you everyone and especially @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to validate mandatory form input do not use `EditorFor()` if your MVC bellow 5.1, just using `TextBoxFor()` thank you

Answer (score 1):

Insert `@` Like: `@required="required"`

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me (ASP.NET MVC 5). Add

```
@data_val="true"
```

with

```
@required="required"
```

Final code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @data_val="true", @required="required" } })
```

by adding , the form started to use jquery validator.